# How to choose using Collection<Id> rather than Collection<String>, or the opposite?

Tags: salesforce-id, string, collection

During a conference call with a collegue, I saw him using list of Strings while using Ids, referencing to a list of Ids ;
I asked him why this choice, he answered *'Ids are strings so it's about the same'*.

Naturally, I would use **List<Id> idList** rather than **List<String> idList** .

Are they really differences, and uses cases where we really have to think about the use of the lists, to choose between one case rather than the other ?

Comment: use `List<Id>` - much better self-documented code; built-in error checking; built in IDE support for available methods.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both `String` and `Id` are [primitive data types in apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_primitives.htm). Consider below scenario:

```
public class poc {
    static List<Id> ids = new List<Id>();
    public static void check() {
        try {
            ids.add('invalid_id');
            System.debug('ids => '+ids);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            System.debug('ERROR => '+ex.getMessage());
        }
    }   
}
```

Here when you invoke `check()`, it will throw error saying `Invalid id: invalid_id` as 'invalid_id' is actually not a valid salesforce `Id`.

However when you define `List<String>` variable and add `Id` to that variable, apex internally converts `Id` datatype to `String` and adds it.

**IMPORTANT:**

1. When you expect a collection to have `Id`s, then always define use type `Id` only so that you do not add string inadvertantly. This is a best practice.
2. When you dont know which data type it may contain, you can use String and later convert String to `Id` using `Id.valueOf(String)`. But before converting, it is best practice to check if its valid `Id` using `instanceof`. Example below:

   ```
   System.debug('aa' instanceof Id); //false
   System.debug('0010K00001fr5LhQAI' instanceof Id); //true
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Ids are a subset of Strings. The advantage of using Id is that it has its own methods that you could use from here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_id.htm

But in a lot of cases I'd say it's not that big of a deal if you use string instead of Id. I try to use Id if I know for sure it is an Id. I think it makes the code cleaner